# Google Drive file icons broken and I cannot download files

Tags: google-drive

Recently I have noticed that the files icons in my google drive does not appear correctly (see image below) then I discovered that I also cannot download my file.

I tried on different devices, different browsers and using different Google accounts with the same results.

Any help is appreciated

Update: the problem solved when using VPN. Is there a method to retrieve the service without VPN?

[image]

Comment: Can you back up the local files (for certain), break the sync, restart the computer and set up Google Drive again.  Does this help?

Comment: I'm experiencing similar issues with various Google products.

Comment: Is your Google Account properly active and activated?

Comment: @John I don't have Google Drive for Desktop. I am facing this issue with the online version of Google Drive. I don't know what you mean by active and activated account but I have tried with different Google accounts

Comment: Update: the problem solved when using VPN. Is there a method to retrieve the service without VPN?

Answer (score 0):

This commonly issue in your Browser, to fix this try to update your Browser, then relogged-in
if this screen came from Google Drive Desktop app, you need to update that software too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the information in the help article for Google Workspace administrators might help you [Drive and Sites firewall and proxy settings](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en).

> For users on your network to access Google Drive, Google Docs editors, and new Google Sites, connect your firewall rules to the following hosts and ports. Otherwise, users might be blocked or denied access to these services.

Below the above paragraph is a list of hosts and ports. Better to directly review the source as will not be helpful for anyone to see an obsolete list.

You might need to pass this information to your network administrator or ISP and request them to do the proper adjustments in their service in order that you don't have to use a VPN.